# Limit the length of an dynamically chaning array before interact with it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, maxlength

i use d3.js and i got an array and it's length dynamically changes by interaction.
So now i wonder, how i can make a limit the length of the array, BEFORE i interact the first time with it and dynamically change the length?

So, for example at the beginning i want the maximum length of the array is 4 and then when i interact with the array, it can never be longer than the length of 4?

So let's say the name of the array is `array`. I wonder if i can solve this problem with normal javascript code or d3.js code like `d3.max` or  `array.map`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered here: [Is it possible to create a fixed length array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988909/is-it-possible-to-create-a-fixed-length-array-in-javascript)

But in general, you can achieve this behavior by making ensuring that your array does not exceed a specific value. e.g.

```
if (array.length < 4)
  array.push(x);
else
  console.log('The array is already filled');
```

Comment: thanks, but can you explain the usage of push() in your code? The goal is to limit the array and make it not growing bigger than 4. In your code you say, if the array is shorter than 4, add `x` to the end of the array?

Comment: This is snippet is meant for the part in your code when you interact (e.g. push a new element at the back) with your array. At some point, you have to add elements to it, right?

It's easier if you provide a concrete example to further discuss this. ;)

Comment: Hey Johannes, it is this way: i have many nodes and i can click on 2 nodes and highlight all nodes between. This number of nodes are stored in an array. When i click on 2 new nodes and highlight all  nodes between those 2 new nodes, the array length dynamically changes. So for example i want to create a button and push on it. and each time i push on it, the length of the array will be limited to a certain value, for example 4. So that's why i was confusing about your using of `push()`.

Comment: are you familiar with d3?

Comment: i use plunker, is that also ok?