# Set max parameters of a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm going through some tutorials of JS arrays and I have a question.

Say I create a 2d array like so:

```
var arr = new Array(10);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = new Array(10);
}
```

How can I set max parameters of a 2d array, so that when I append values to certain cells it's rejected?

For example,

```
arr[1][2] = "one";
arr[5][15] = "two";
```

`arr[5][15]` falls out of the parameters set in the code that creates the array, but is still created and passed into the array, when it shouldn't be.

After reading comments - new code below:

```
let grid = []

const createGrid = (x) => {

    grid = new Array(x);

    for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        grid[i] = new Array(10);
    }
    if(Object.seal) { 
        Object.seal(grid);
    }
}

createGrid(10);

grid[1][2] = "one";
grid[5][15] = "two";

console.log(grid);
```

This doesn't work, but when setting the first value to greater than the set length of the grid (`grid[15][5]`) it get's rejected, but not when it's set to`grid[5][15]`.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988909/is-it-possible-to-create-a-fixed-length-array-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a fixed length array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988909/is-it-possible-to-create-a-fixed-length-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @Valentino, I've tried the `Object.seal` approach - still not working

Comment: Defining custom behavior on built-in object was made easy using Proxies, have you tried the solution I gave you ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for that matter:

```
const handler = {
  set(target, prop, value, receiver){
    if (prop > target.length - 1)
      throw new RangeError()

    return Reflect.set(...arguments)
  }
}

const createDimension = size => new Proxy(new Array(size), handler)
const grid = createDimension(10)

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  grid[i] = createDimension(10)
}

grid[2][0] = 'foo'
console.log(grid)

// Should throw range error
grid[2][12] = 'foo'
console.log(grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have sealed only the root array, but forgot to do so for child arrays. This is what you should do:

```js
let grid = []

const createGrid = (x) => {

    grid = new Array(x);

    for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        grid[i] = new Array(10);
    }
    if(Object.seal) { 
        Object.seal(grid);
        grid.forEach(Object.seal) // <----- you forgot this
        // the above line is the shorter version of this:
        // grid.forEach(childGrid => Object.seal(childGrid))
        
    }
}

createGrid(10);

grid[1][2] = "one";
grid[5][15] = "two";

console.log(grid);
```

Comment: The output is undefined?  So setting `grid[1][2]` and `grid[5][15]` isn't working now? Is that because of `Object.seal`?

Comment: @user172127 yes you can run my code by pressing the button "Run code snippet". You can remove the added line and see that the sealing works.